# Avoiding S33E abend at program end

Tags: c, multithreading, mainframe, zos

I know that generally [`S33E` abends](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.ieah700/m015136.htm) are ignored because they happen all the time, but I still think they are messy, and so I am trying to get my C language program to end cleanly in this regard. I did have a few threads that weren't ended explicitly and just ended when the main program ended, but I have cleaned them up and I use a `PTHREAD_QUERY` (via [`BPX4PTQ`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.bpxb100/ptq.htm)) to discover whether I still have any threads still running. It says I now have zero threads. Also if I stop it in the debugger (`dbx`) just before the end of the program, the only active thread is the main thread.

I have created a very simple program as follows, and this even causes the S33E slip trap to fire.

```
#pragma runopts(POSIX(ON))
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#define _OPEN_THREADS
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void * MyThread(void * arg)
{
  printf("Entered MyThread routine\n");
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t tid;
  void    * ret;

  if (pthread_create(&tid, NULL, MyThread, NULL))
  {
    perror("pthread_create error");
  }

  if (pthread_join(tid, &ret))
  {
    perror("pthread_join error");
  }

//if (pthread_detach(&tid))
//{
//  perror("pthread_detach error");
//}

  return(0);
}
```

I removed the call to `pthread_detach` because I discovered that `pthread_join` (which waits for the thread to end) also detaches it - says so in the manual too.

I am running the program as a started task. When it ends the S33E abend slip trap fires. This **only** happens when I run the program as a started task.

So then I tried an even simpler program thus:-

```
#pragma runopts(POSIX(ON))
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  printf("A very simple program\n");

  return(0);
}
```

and ran this as a started task, and even this, which has created no threads, is causing the S33E abend slip trap to fire.

So what else can I do to get rid of the `S33E` abends?

Currently the slip on S33E is set up for ACTION=NODUMP. If I change it to take a dump, what should I look for to discover the thread that hasn't ended? And what will it mean in the case where I have no created threads?

**Or am I misunderstanding what `S33E` abend is telling me?**

Comment: What task does the dump show is the guilty party?

Comment: Hi @Hogstrom - sorry for the delay in coming back to you. I tried to both simplify and expand on my question. If looking in the dump is still the best way forward, can you tell me what I should be looking for. Cheers!

Comment: Is this batch? I’ve seen these happen before and they’re something to do with the initiator. A long long time ago I did look at these, but I don’t remember what was triggering them, and obviously I never dug deeply. Because there’s a SLIP trap, to get the dump you’ll need to create a SLIP that has your jobname and COMP=33E.

Comment: @zarchasmpgmr - this is a started task - does that make it in batch too? JCL in PROCLIB. I am happy to create the slip so that it takes the dump, just need to know what to look for in the dump once I get it, to determine why when running the program as a started task I get the S33E abend at shutdown and not any other time.

Comment: Ah. That’s not batch in the traditional sense, which is a job running within an initiator, so there’s an extra level of TCBs. For debugging, the important thing is which module it is. I would not be surprised if it’s not in your code. Please let us know what you find.

Comment: For what it's worth, terminating your main thread with "exit()" instead of "return()" *sometimes* fixes these 33E abends, especially after you've used the pthreads library.